# PHP Regex finding blocks of text seperated by two line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex and having some issues with it.

I have a text file with blocks of text that I want to put into an array. Each text block starts with "Hand #" and ends with "** Deck **" and is separated by line breaks. It looks like something like this:

```
Hand #...random digits
blah
blah
blah
blah
** Deck **...random digits

Hand #...random digits
blah
blah
blah
blah
** Deck **...random digits

Hand #...random digits
blah
blah
blah
blah
** Deck **...random digits
```

I want each array element to include the text between each pair of "Hand #" and "** Deck **". What i've tried so far which isn't returning any results:

```
preg_match_all("%Hand #(.*?)[*][*] Deck [*][*]%", $file, $array);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the problem ? and do you want those random digits too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` by default does not match line breaks. You can change this with the `s` (singleline or "dotall") modifier:

```
preg_match_all("%Hand #(.*?)[*][*] Deck [*][*]%s", $file, $array);
```

If you don't want your result to contain `Hand #` and `** Deck **`, an alternative to capturing would be lookarounds:

```
preg_match_all("%(?<=Hand #).*?(?=[*][*] Deck [*][*])%s", $file, $array);
```

If you do want them, you can simply remove the parentheses from the first pattern.

Comment: @user2441938 If this solves your problem then please accept it as an answer.